# Overwrite an existing php variable value in a file using php

Tags: php, fopen

I have a file named config.php with several variable configuration values including the following one:

```
$config['currencyCode'] = 'USD';
```

I need to open config.php file and change the value of `$config['currencyCode']` **to another value and save it**.

Is it possible via php using fopen or some other manner? Changing a specific variable value in the file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but not as an specific variable only. You will have to write whole file again. 1- Include config file 2- Write all variables to the file using fopen and only changing value of desired variable.

Comment: Do you include that file in your code? You could simply update the value of that variable in the same scope

Comment: I think it's better to have CSV format for a file that needs to be re-written at run time. After that you can load the csv file using a simple fopen() and explode() function.

Comment: The config.php file is called in a separate ajax call and I need the value to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary?

```
// config.php
$config['currencyCode'] = 'USD';

// shop.php
require 'config.php';
// can alter the value if you want to
$config['currencyCode'] = 'GBP';
```

It will not change the value in `config.php`, but you can override it if you want to, which is probably better

Comment: I need the variable to be updated in config.php file as config.php is called from another file using ajax.

Comment: Why not store this data in a database, and have your code extract and update the database value

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the value of currencyCode in database and can retrieve it in config file as per the below code.

```
$select = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT currencyCode FROM tablename");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
echo $row['currencyCode'];
```

Also you can update the value of currencyCode in database with below query.

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE tablename SET currencyCode = [value]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the value by reading the file contents, replacing the value you want, and writing it back into the file:

```
$file = 'config.php';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$contents = str_replace("$['currencyCode'] = 'USD';", "$['currencyCode'] = 'GBP';", $contents);
file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```